# Using tuples to update an inventory file under multiple groups

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I am trying to update my inventory file in multiple places for a specific playbook.  This is the trimmed down playbook.

FYI. the referenced configurations have been removed in the real environment.

```
vars:
  instance_groups: ['ec2_instances','docker','ubuntu']

<snip>
- name: persist new hosts in inventory
  lineinfile:
    line: "{{ item[1] }}"
    path: "{{ inventory_file }}"
    insertafter: "{{ item[0] }}"
   loop: "{{ instance_groups | product(dns_names) | list }}"
   when: dns_names is defined
```

instance_groups is a list and dns_names is a list

I'm expecting the loop to insert each dns_name to each of the instance_groups, however, it only inserts for the first of the instance groups.

Sample output in the file:

```
[ec2_instances]
ec2-3-219-45-179.compute-1.amazonaws.com
ec2-44-212-11-160.compute-1.amazonaws.com
ec2-44-192-37-35.compute-1.amazonaws.com

[docker]

[ubuntu]
```

EXPECTED outcome:

```
[ec2_instances]
ec2-3-219-45-179.compute-1.amazonaws.com
ec2-44-212-11-160.compute-1.amazonaws.com
ec2-44-192-37-35.compute-1.amazonaws.com

[docker]
ec2-3-219-45-179.compute-1.amazonaws.com
ec2-44-212-11-160.compute-1.amazonaws.com
ec2-44-192-37-35.compute-1.amazonaws.com

[ubuntu]
ec2-3-219-45-179.compute-1.amazonaws.com
ec2-44-212-11-160.compute-1.amazonaws.com
ec2-44-192-37-35.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```

Here is a the detailed playbook output
https://gist.github.com/traxeon/190f462a3fcc933e60996e63a4b35259

I welcome any insights anyone may have towards a solution.  Thanks.

I was expecting the loop to populate the dns_names under each group header in the file.

Comment: `lineinfile` inserts **one** line if it does not exist. Quoting the doc: `See the ansible.builtin.replace module if you want to change multiple, similar lines or check ansible.builtin.blockinfile if you want to insert/update/remove a block of lines in a file. For other cases, see the ansible.builtin.copy or ansible.builtin.template modules`. You might also want to check the `ini_file` module. . Meanwhile, since this looks like an attempt of dynamic inventory, check https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/amazon/aws/aws_ec2_inventory.html

Comment: thank you for the feedback.  i thought that because it was inside a loop, it would insert one time per each insert case as the item variables change.

Comment: I dont need to replace a value or insert a block.  I need to insert a line in three different location in the file driven by the block headers.  i updated the example above for added clarify.  I will look at the two references again as I originally did not think they would fit my use case.